# what is function_foo.boolean = True in django's model?

Tags: django, model

Following is a code from https://github.com/jeffbowen/django-logicaldelete/blob/master/logicaldelete/models.py

I am trying to understand what `active.boolean = True` does in the code.

```
class Model(models.Model):
    """
    This base model provides date fields and functionality to enable logical
    delete functionality in derived models.
    """

    date_created  = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_removed  = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    objects = managers.LogicalDeletedManager()

    def active(self):
        return self.date_removed == None
    active.boolean = True  # <------------------- HERE

    def delete(self):
        self.date_removed = timezone.now
        self.save()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: It defines the method as boolean (which it is), so if used by admin site will use the default icons for such a field (instead of True or False as it will without it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, functions and methods are objects like anything else. This code is simply adding an attribute `boolean` to the `active` function, which can be used elsewhere in the code. It doesn't have any significance in and of itself.

In this case, it's used by the admin list display code, to display a nice icon in the list instead of True/False.